# Will valdr support angular 2?

Tags: angular, valdr

I couldn't find anything in the valdr documentation about the support of the upcomming angular 2. Does anybody know if valdr is usable with angularJS 2?

Comment: You can raise an issue on github.

Comment: It's a question, not an issue, is it?

Comment: It doesn't support 2.x for now, sounds like an issue to me (actually, I've seen a lot of 'issues' on GH that were actual SO questions, and none of them was ignored or declined). It is unlikely that somebody has an answer here, unless the developer provides voluntary support on SO.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @estus, now I know that it's unsupported. I was following the project's site btw, which says "Support: Ask a question on Stack Overflow and tag it with valdr"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I work for the company that developed valdr I can tell you that I am pretty sure that there will be a support for Angular2 in near future. There are plans for it, but I can't give you any details about the time nor the complete feature set. It will be a completely new Angular2 module. I will keep you updated.

Comment: any news on the Angular 2 validation?

Comment: the development of valdr2 should start soon, I will get back to you if there are any news

Comment: Any news on this issue?